# This JavaScript syntax I haven't seen till now, what does it do really?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, operators

Today I saw a JavaScript syntax (when invoking a function) that is unfamiliar to me. It was like:

```
def('Person') ({
  init: function(name) {this.name=name;}
  ,speak: function(text) {alert(text || 'Hi, my name is ' + this.name);}
});
```

, and

```
def('Ninja') << Person ({
  kick: function() {this.speak('I kick u!');}
});
```

1: What happens with the object within the parentheses in the first example? It is handled by the `def` function somehow, but I don't understand what is going on here (see the `def` function below). Where does the object go?

2: About the same thing again, but a use of the `<<` operator that I never seen (I think!). What's that all about?

The code is from http://gist.github.com/474994, where Joe Dalton has made a small JavaScript-OO-inheritance thing (it is apparently a fork of someone else's work, but quite thoroughly rewritten, as it seems). Maybe you want to check it out there for the stuff referenced by the `def` function, which I give you here:

```
function def(klassName, context) {
  context || (context = global);

  // Create class on given context (defaults to global object)
  var Klass =
    context[klassName] = function Klass() {

      // Called as a constructor
      if (this != context) {

        // Allow the init method to return a different class/object
        return this.init && this.init.apply(this, arguments);
      }

      // Called as a method
      // defer setup of superclass and plugins
      deferred._super = Klass;
      deferred._plugins = arguments[0] || { };
    };

  // Add static helper method
  Klass.addPlugins = addPlugins;

  // Called as function when not
  // inheriting from a superclass
  deferred = function(plugins) {
    return Klass.addPlugins(plugins);
  };

  // valueOf is called to set up
  // inheritance from a superclass
  deferred.valueOf = function() {
    var Superclass = deferred._super;
    if (!Superclass)
        return Klass;
    Subclass.prototype = Superclass.prototype;
    Klass.prototype = new Subclass;
    Klass.superclass = Superclass;
    Klass.prototype.constructor = Klass;
    return Klass.addPlugins(deferred._plugins);
  };
  return deferred;
}
```

Comment: the original seems to be Tobias Schneiders https://github.com/tobeytailor/def.js

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1: The call `def('Person')` returns a function, which is called with the object as parameter. It's the same principle as:

```
function x() {
  return function(y) { alert(y); }
}

x()('Hello world!');
```

2: The `<<` operator is the left shift operator. It shifts an integer value a specific number of bits to the left. I haven't found any reference for any other use for it, and there is no operator overloading in Javascript, so I can't make any sense out of using it on a function. So far it looks like a typo to me.

#### Edit:

As Tim explained, the shift operator is just used to induce a call to the `valueOf` method. It works like an overload of all operators, taking over the original purpose and doing something completely different.

Comment: Ah, of course. Neat. Thanks.  
But what about the operator thing?

Comment: @npup: I haven't been able to make any sense of the operator thing. Se my addition above.

Comment: The operator (whose basic usage is not alien to me): Yeah it looks really weird. Maybe it turns out as a no-op that is just used here to make the subclassing declarations look a certain way? Huh.
Thanks for the answers!

Comment: It appears that the << operator in this case is intended to denote inheritance. I could not find where that operator was defined however. Seems like non standard JavaScript.

Comment: The returned object has defined the function `valueOf`, which is called when the left-shift is performed on the object. Apparently the << is supposed to resemble Ruby's inheritance syntax (I'm not familiar with Ruby), and by defining `valueOf` they're able to hijack the left-shift operation to perform the superclassing, while getting a pretty syntax. I imagine you could swap out another operator that would call `valueOf` on the two objects and get a similar effect.

Comment: @tim Oh, thanks for that explanation! A bit fishy stuff that, but a bit cool too. Fish are normally cool I suppose.

Comment: @npup: Yeah, it's extremely fiendish how it works, but admittedly it's also pretty cool.

Comment: @Tim: I see, it's just misusing the operator to call the valueOf method. I'm not surprised, the code has several constructs where it's using side effects and discarding the original purpose of operators.

Comment: @Guffa: That code does seem to be a pretty extreme case of operator abuse...Admittedly, I hope I never see it anywhere else, heh, but I'm sure that's wishful thinking.

Comment: As the owner explains in his example:

// The bit shift `<<` is just a snazzy way to invoke the valueOf() of the subclass.
// You could use `+` or `<` or `%` or `^` or `*` or well you get the idea.

Answer (score 6):

Wow, it was convoluted enough for my tiny brain to understand, but I feel a lot better now knowing exactly how it works :) Thanks to @Tim for pointing out the `valueOf()` trick.

The general case of creating a `"class"` using:

```
def ("ClassName") ({
    init: function() { .. },
    foo: function() { .. }
});
```

is trivial, as the first call to `def` returns a function that accepts an object, and copies the properties of the passed in object, to the prototype of `ClassName`.

The more interesting case of using `<<` to subclass relies on the evaluation order of the expression, as well as the attempted coercing of any object to a value by the implicit call to `valueOf()`. The underlying trick is basically a shared variable that records the super class and the properties to be applied to it. The expression,

```
def("ClassName") << ParentClass({ .. })
```

will be evaluated as follows:

1. `def("ClassName")` is called, and creates a global object `ClassName` and returns its constructor function. Let's call this returned object - `initializeMeLater`.
2. `ParentClass(..)` is called which stores the reference to `ParentClass`, and the passed in object/properties in a shared variable.
3. `initializeMeLater.valueOf()` is called, which gets the reference to the parent class, and the properties from that shared variable, and sets up the prototypes.
4. `valueOf` is called on the return value from step 2 which is useless and has no effect, as we have already setup the superclass relationship in step 3.

The code is trying to emulate Ruby syntax for creating subclasses which goes like:

```
class Child < Parent
    def someMethod
        ...
    end
end
```