# Operator Overloading Javascript? (def.js)

Tags: javascript, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript syntax I haven’t seen till now, what does it do really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245639/javascript-syntax-i-havent-seen-till-now-what-does-it-do-really)

Just saw http://github.com/tobeytailor/def.js today, and I don't understand how this works:

```
def ("Ninja") << Person ({
    init: function(name){
        this._super();
    },

    kick: function(){
        this.speak("I kick u!");
    }
});
```

Looking through the code for def.js, I don't see anything mentioning the `<<` operator. How is this pseudo operator overloading happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript syntax I haven't seen till now, what does it do really?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245639/javascript-syntax-i-havent-seen-till-now-what-does-it-do-really).  Answered in that question as well, see the edit and comments on the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that when posting. voted to close.