# Is "parentheses after function call " a correct/legal use of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, parentheses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript syntax I haven't seen till now, what does it do really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245639/javascript-syntax-i-havent-seen-till-now-what-does-it-do-really)

I was checking out a library called [def.js](https://github.com/tobeytailor/def.js) which makes JavaScript objects inherit in a similar fashion as Ruby. But the thing that I couldn't really get was the way JavaScript was used in the example provided:

```
def ("Person") ({
    init: function(name){
        this.name = name;
    },

    speak: function(text){
        alert(text || "Hi, my name is " + this.name);
    }
});

def ("Ninja") << Person ({
    init: function(name){
        this._super();
    },

    kick: function(){
        this.speak("I kick u!");
    }
});

var ninjy = new Ninja("JDD");

ninjy.speak();
ninjy.kick();
```

in short, the two points are:

1. def ("Person")({}); // parentheses after function call
2. def ("Ninja") << Person ({}); // two function calls seperated by the operator <<

Is this a correct/legal use of JavaScript, and if it is, what's it's meaning i.e. how is interpreted by the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def("Person")({...});
```

is basically chained function calls. It means:

1. Pass the string `"Person"` to the function call `def()`.
2. `def()` returns a function which can then be called.
3. Pass an object `{...}` as an argument to the function that is returned by `def()`.

Not sure about the `<<` operator as I've not encountered it in JS before. I would think it's the left bit-shift operator, but I don't know how it applies to functions.

Comment: The `<<` operator is left shift. Since it doesn't know how to shift anything but a number, it calls `valueOf` on its operand. It's this `valueOf` function that sets up the inheritance, so any operator would probably do the same thing.