# What's the difference between those two function definition?

Tags: javascript

1 style

```
var x = function(xx) {
}
```

another

```
x : function (xx) {
}
```

what's the difference between those two styles

Comment: Isn't the second one only possible inside a "json" structure?

Comment: inside a Javascript object literal, to be specific. JSON can't serialise functions

Comment: Are you asking about what the difference between:
`a.x = function(xx){}` and `a = { x: function(xx) {} }` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20297761/1048572

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the result of evaluating a function expression (i.e. the resulting function — evaluation is not calling) is assigned to a variable.

In the second case, you start with a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and then have a syntax error.

You probably meant:

```
var foo = {
    x : function (xx) {
    }
}
```

… which is an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals) where the function is assigned to a property of the new object instead of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The first is an assignment of an anonymous function into a variable `x`.

The seconds isn’t valid JavaScript at all, at least how you are showing it.

If this is inside an object, like this:

```
var dog = {
   x : function (xx) {
   }
};
```

It is simply an property containing an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

The first is assigning a local variable to a function definition

The second is using object notation to assign a function to a object member.
i.e.

```
var obj = {
  x : function (y) { }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

In the 1st case we are binding the function to javascript variable which is in the global scope. So in 1st case that function gets bound to the 'x' key in windows object.

Where as in second case that function gets bound to the object in which you are planning to add 'x' key.